# Align columns in VI

Tags: vim, vi

I have a bunch of lines that I'd like to split into two columns, and get the data from each column.  The data looks something like this:

```
current_well.well_number
current_well.well_name
current_well.well_type_code
well_location.section
well_location.range
```

Essentially what I'd like to do is split the line based off of the period, turn the data into two columns, and then grab the data for each column.  I know this can be done in Excel, but I'm really interested in VIs solution for this problem.  I know that

```
%s/\./
```

will format the string with empty spaces.  But once I have the data looking like:

```
current_well    well_number
current_well    well_name
current_well    well_type_code
well_location   section
well_location   range
```

How do I grab all the values for each column so I can paste it into another application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this problem a number of times.  Changing the dots to tabs will line them up *mostly* nice, but not really.  It's true that all the columns will start on a tabstop, but there's no guarantee that they'll be on the same tabstop.  For instance, if this was your original text:

```
lt1tab.value1
gt1tabstop.value2
```

and you do:

```
%s/\./\t/g
```

and assuming a tabstop is 8 spaces, you'll get:

```
lt1tab  value1
gt1tabstop    value2
```

What you might want to do instead is remove everything but the last column (or whichever column you want).  For instance:

```
%s/^.*\.//
```

will leave you with:

```
value1
value2
```

Which you can easily copy and paste.

---

If you don't have to use Vim, you can use unix's `cut` to do what you want:

```
cut -f2 -d. input_file > output_file
```

Comment: This worked great!  To get values left of the period I used the following expression:

%s/\..*$//

Answer (score 17):

The linux column command works well for creating the columns

```
:%!column -s . -t
```

Then use block copy.

Comment: I can't find documentation on `%!`. I know `!` calls an external command, but what does `%` do in this context? Without it, this command apparently spawns a process that never ends.

Comment: I would add spaces if needed with `%!column -t -s. -o'   '`

Comment: @DavidKennedy See help for `:range!` and `:%`.

Answer (score 7):

One option is to use this [Align plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) to line up the periods so you can more easily select a column in Visual Block mode.  e.g. if you do this:

```
:%Align \.
```

You'll end up with:

```
current_well  . well_number
current_well  . well_name
current_well  . well_type_code
well_location . section
well_location . range
```

If you don't want to use a plugin, try padding your columns with spaces.  e.g. for your text:

```
:%s/\v(.*)\.(.*)/\=printf("%-16s %s", submatch(1), submatch(2))/
```

That'll leave you with:

```
current_well     well_number
current_well     well_name
current_well     well_type_code
well_location    section
well_location    range
```

Then you can `Ctrl-V` and select a column of text to copy.  Just make sure you pick a column width wider than your widest value.

Comment: Wow, an excellent answer, I wasn't aware of printf/submatch in a substitution; thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I do this all the time, simply by padding with a lot of space:

```
%s/./                     /
```

Then `<c-v>` to enter block mode in the empty space, draw the column position I want, `<` to shift the text to the right toward my column, then hold down `.`.  Takes seconds.

Another way you can do it if you know the specific column position you want to line up on: go to the first line and start recording (`qq`), find your delimeter (`f.`), insert a bunch of space (`20i <esc>`), delete space back to a specific column (`d15|`), then move down a line (`j`). Then you just hold down shift and roll your fingers across `@Q` a bunch of times (or use a count `10@q`) until all the columns are lined up. :)

Comment: Despite some of the really clever ways to do this, I usually remember this one. After the substitution, you can also do `:g/./normal 15|dw`.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the above methods with block select and/or Excel are easier. But I'm a masochist and I decided to assume you didn't have access to either of those and try to do it with only vi commands. Here's the horrible thing I thought up:

My basic plan is to turn the list of joined columns into two lists, one after the other. This basically involves breaking each row into two lines, then copying every other line to the end of the file.

So, first we have to break each line into two lines with this command:

```
:%s/\./^M/
```

Next, swing by the bottom of the file and create an empty line, then return to the first line. This will help with readability later.

```
Go[Esc]
:1
```

Now, you need to map the following sequence to your favorite key:

```
:map [Key] mkjddGp'kj
```

(For the record, this marks the current row, deletes the row below it, pastes that row at the bottom of the file, returns to the row you started from, and then moves to the next row.)

Finally, press the mapped key once for every row in your list. So, with the example list, you'd press it 5 times. Make sure you start from the first line in the list!!

What you'll have at the end is the following:

```
current_well
current_well
current_well
well_location
well_location

well_number
well_name
well_type_code
section
range
```

You can now easily copy each list to wherever you need to put them.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

1. w (or W for WORDS) jumps to next word,
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> gets the word under cursor and pastes it into command-line

Now you have to chain those commands in a loop and then output them in your own manner.

Answer (score 0):

Why not block visual mode ? C-v, select what you want, and paste it in some other application.
For that kind of pasting, you should probably set

```
:set guioptions+=a
```

as well.

Hmm, now that I've re-read your question. Are you asking how to divide the data into columns, or how to paste it in some other app ?

---

I think I got it now (3rd reading).

Do as you've done and get the spaces where the dots used to be. Then do another substitution, and replace the spaces with tabs, each tab being, 15 or something. It will line them up nicely.
Then you can select and copy them to wherever.

You can also match the regex to select the second column for example, but although it is light up like a christmas tree, you won't be able to yank it.

Answer (score 0):

You can select columns in gvim by typing either <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd> (depending on if you are using windows insert key mappings) and then selecting with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl V selects a column

Comment: Actually, it selects a block. I've yet to find an editor which can select columns of text.

Answer (score 0):

I'd convert the dots to tabs, then block select each column:

:%s/\./*CtrlV-Tab*/g

*CtrlV* to then block select the columns.

Or, as you'd have tab separated values, they will paste directly into columns in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the file:

```
!}awk -F. '{print $1}' >> %
```

You will be told the file has changed. Select the `L` (load) option.
Add a blank line under the original lines, go back to the top.

```
for(i=1;i<=NR;i++);print $2 >> %
```

Again select the `L` option

Delete the original lines.
You now have the first and second parts in two groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
nnoremap <BS> v"by:%!column -t -s<C-r>b -o'      '<CR>
```

This is a nice solution following on from @NES & @SergioAraujo idea. Put it in your vimrc.

USAGE. Move the cursor to the delimiter. Then hit Backspace.

Explanation we use the named register b to hold our delimiter. Then substitute it as the variable for the --separator option of the column UNIX utility.

And Backspace is a good key because in normal mode  is the same as h. But then again you might also be prone to hitting it accidentally.