# what is the fastest way to achieve this kind of alignment?

Tags: sed, vim

```
abcd "123"
abcdabcd "123123"
aaaaaa "1234"
```

How can be above key-value block be indented to as below.   value should always start at same position irrespective of key length.

```
abcd        "123"
abcdabcd    "123123"
aaaaaa      "1234"
```

Comment: This is called alignment, not indentation.

Comment: Use the `column` command

Comment: @Sundeep there is no such command.

Comment: @svlasov Linux command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17030109/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+align+columns

Comment: @svlasov not a standard command. Just checked man page on my distro, and the history section says "4.3BSD-Reno". As per https://www.mankier.com/1/column it can be obtained as part of the util-linux package.

Comment: What if the key is too long to fit before the value given whatever length you've set for it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Vim, visually select lines and do `:'<,'>!column -t`

Answer (score 1):

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) perhaps:

```bash
awk '{$1 = sprintf("%-12s", $1); print}' <<BLOCK
abcd "123"
abcdabcd "123123"
aaaaaa "1234"
BLOCK
```

```
abcd         "123"
abcdabcd     "123123"
aaaaaa       "1234"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '# first loop to pull the file into the pattern space (PS)
        :a
        N;$!ba
        # make a copy in the hold space (HS)
        # notice the leading newline
        H
        # swap to the HS
        x
        # remove the second columns
        s/ .*//mg
        # replace all characters (other than newlines) with spaces
        s/[^\n]/ /g
        # second loop and reset substitution flag
        :b;tb
        # remove all first columns mask keeping the longest
        s/^(\n[^\n]+)(\1.*)/\2/;tb
        s/^(\n[^\n]+)\n[^\n]+/\1/;tb
        # swap back to the PS
        x
        # third loop
        :c
        # append the mask to the PS
        G
        # introduce a newline at the start of the line
        s/^/\n/
        # fourth loop
        :d
        # match each character in the first column 
        # with its place in the mask
        s/^(\S*)\n(\S)(.*\n\n) /\1\2\n\3/;td
        # replace the introduced newline line with the remainder 
        # of the mask
        s/\n(.*)\n\n(.*)/\2\1/
        # print the first line
        P
        # reduce the PS by one line and go again
        /^[^\n]+\n/{s///;bc}
        # clear up and finish
        d' file
```

In short, slurp the file into memory and use a copy of the file to identify and create a mask for the longest first column. Then apply the mask to each line.

This is a toy example.

A less complicated solution split into two sed invocations using the same underlying ideas:

```
sed -E 's/ .*//;s/./ /g;G;/^(.*)\n(\1.*)/s//\2/;s/\n.*//;h;$!d
        x;s#.*#1{x;s/^/&/;x}#' file |
sed -Ef - -e 'G;s/^/\n/
             :a;s/^(\S*)\n(\S)(.*) /\1\2\n\3/;ta;s/\n(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1/' file
```

Comment: The 1st one is a clever use of `sed`! :-)))